# Multi threading for reading and writing to SERVER in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have a requirement where I have to write on socket and then read response continuously from socket and process the data.
I have created 2 classes A and B. A has write() and read() api and B has processdata() api.
I have created callback from A::read() to B::processdata().
But i am facing issue with multi threading as as i am new to it.
Thread to read() api has to be always running, but while processing of data in B::processdata(), server is sending some more data on socket read() which i am missing.
Please suggest some design for this issue so that i can keep storing data while my processdata function may finish its work and can comeback again to read data (with small example)?
I was thinking of maintaining 3 threads, 1 for each write , read and processdata. But I am not sure how to comeback to read thread after finishing processdata thread.

Sorry for the long post but I will appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Below is my very high level code design which I am having in my project.

```
 //A.cpp
        class A {
        public:
          void  write();
           void read(b* obj);
        }
        void A::write()
        { 
           //code to write to socket  

          }
        void A::read(b* obj)
        { 
           //code to read from socket  
          // if data received call below function 
          obj->processdata(buffer)
          }

    //B.cpp    
        class B {
        public:
            processdata(buffer)
        }

        void B::processdata(buffer)
        { 
           //code to processdaata from socket  
          }
//Main.cpp
        int main()
        {
          A* objA = new A;
          B* objB = new B;
          objA->write()
          while(1)
           {
             objA->read(objB)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why can't try to make use of Critical sections ? as per my understanding you are asking about thread synchronization ?

Comment: You'll need to either make copies of the contents of `buffer` or use multiple buffers so you can continue to receive data while processing earlier data.  You will have to have some way to store these buffers until `B` can get around to processing them, while having the `B` thread wait for data to be available.  Synchronization between your 2 threads is vital.

Comment: @Akhil: Pardon my naivety but are you talking about making my buffer protected using semaphore/mutex ? My problem here is that while processing data I am blocking read at socket as my code will be processing data.So I wanted help with creating a multithreaded model for same.
Can you help me with small example for that?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Could you please give me a small example ? I would be rather very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: That isn't a trivial batch of code.  Look up the "producer consumer problem".

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm : I don't have issue with buffer corruption or to lock the buffer. My problem lies with inability to read at socket as when i start my processdata , there is something already at socket , which i want to store.But my control return to that point only after finishing the processdata call. Hence, I wanted solution for that.

Comment: The tool you are looking for is called "netcat". You're just reinventing the wheel, badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.cpp

```
extern  CRITICAL_SECTION    g_cCritSec;
        class A {
        public:
          static void  write();
          static void read(void* obj);
        }
        void A::write()
        { 

           EnterCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec);
           //code to write to socket 
           LeaveCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec); 

        }
        void A::read(void* obj)
        { 
           EnterCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec);
           while(1)
           {
              //code to read from socket  
              // if data received call below function 
              // send separate copy of buffer to avoid overrite
              uintptr_t Thread2 = _beginthread( B::processdata, 0, (void *) buffer); 

              //obj->processdata(buffer)
           }
           LeaveCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec);
        }
```

B.cpp

```
  extern    CRITICAL_SECTION    g_cCritSec;
        class B {
        public:
            static processdata( void *buffer)
        }

        void B::processdata(void *buffer)
        {  
           Buffer *bufferReceive = (Buffer*)buffer;
           //code to processdaata from socket   
        }
```

Main.cpp

```
CRITICAL_SECTION    g_cCritSec;
        int main()
        {

          InitializeCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec); 
          B* objB = new B;
          objA->write();
          uintptr_t Thread1 = _beginthread( A::read, 0, (void *) objB); 

          DeleteCriticalSection(&g_cCritSec); 
        }
```

will this answer helps you ? A minimal multithreaded application that will start `Thread1` as the static memeber funcation `A::Read` as the routine(we need to define the memeber function as static to use as thread call back). From `Read` Function it will start another thread with copy of `buffer` passing to it. Here both the threads will executes simultaneously

Comment: Wow. Just the answer I was looking for. Thanks mate.
 I have one more query, for Threading and socket purpose shall i use Boost Libs ?
I read c++11 has thread support but when i use "thread t", I get error saying "error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std' " :(
Also, I have to make this code independent of OS, as can be cross compiled on Linux as well as windows.
Can Please you suggest some thing regarding this also?

Comment: If it is solving your problem, please make it as accepted answer.. Try to include pthread.h and use pthread_t (not pthread t)class to create threads. please refer 
pthread_create function for creating posix threads.